# Re-request data when react prop changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react-router and react 16.4. When calling history.push to update the URL query parameters, the page will not reload but I want to re-request the data via AJAX. I am currently using getDerivedStateFromProps and componentDidUpdate to listen for props changes, but I found that when props changes When componentDidUpdate is also triggered, should I use componentDidUpdate directly? How do I perform a function that re-requests data when a URL query changes?
This is part of my code：

```js
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, prevState) {
        const page = qs.parse(location.search)['page'] || 1
        if (page != prevState.page) {
            return {
                page,
                need_update: true
            }
        }
        return null
    }
componentDidUpdate() {
        if (this.state.need_update) {
            this.getData()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code might work if you use componentDidUpdate more like this:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevProps !== this.props) {
    //do stuff here 
  }
}
```

It literally compares new props to previous props, and you can compare state the same way.